# Paperclip fit image in frame and keep it ratio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, paperclip, watermark

I'm working on generating a style for open graph meta datas.
I chose to fit the original picture of a model into a frame of 320x480 whatever the original dimension of the picture.
The goal is to have the original image resized with ratio kept and blank filled with white or transparent.

I tried several types

```
has_attached_file :picture, processors: [:watermark], styles: {
  [..other styles]
  sharing_no_wm: '320x480[^][>][<][!][]'
  sharing: { geometry: '320x480>', watermark_path: "watermark_path", gravity: 'Center', background: 'red', extent: '320x480'}
}, default_url: ':placeholder'
```

As I wrote I tried every style (`!`,`>`,`<`,...) but never got what I wanted.

- When the dimensions are 320x480 the ratio is not respected
- When the ratio is respected the frame is not 320x480

I also tried to set `:convert_options => {:sharing_no_wm => "-gravity [C]center -extent 320x480"}`. 
=> this fails with `unrecognized option '-gravity ...'`

To resume my wish : allways have a result image of 320x480 with the original image fitted in and ratio kept.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert_options like the below example:

```
  has_attached_file :picture, 
                    styles: {thumb: '200x112>'},
                    convert_options: {
                      thumb: '-gravity center -background white -extent 200x112'
                    }
```

You can find more info for convert command at the below link:

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Comment: Like I said on my post I tried convert options but paperclip return with `unrecognized option '-gravity ...'` :/

Comment: @ThibaudRenaux ImageMagick installed on the computer? If it is not installed, you must install ImageMagick. Look this: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor

Comment: I have image magick on my mac (version 7.0.7-24) I guess it's a paperclip miss syntax

Comment: @ThibaudRenaux I agree. Could you try to use it as in my answer? I am using like this and it is running well.